# When a parameter is null, Linq fails while creating projection list

Tags: linq, nullable

I am trying to get a list of MemberMaintenanceData objects through Linq as shown below. The problem is, whenever m.StartDate is null it is throwing NullObjectReference error.

```
var filteredMembers = from m in members.ToList()
    select new MemberMaintenanceData
         {

               MemberName = m.Name,
               SSN = m.SSN,
               PlanName = m.PlanName,
               EffectiveDate = m.StartDate ?? null,
               //EffectiveDate = m.StartDate ?? DateTime.Now,
               GroupName = ""
          };

public class MemberMaintenanceData
{

    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public string PlanName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

In the MemberMaintenanceData EffectiveDate is declared as nullable and I am checking whether it is null or not. Strangely EffectiveDate = m.StartDate ?? DateTime.Now line works fine. Please let me know how to resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: My first guess would be the questionmark in your declaration of EffectiveDate. But I'm not an expert

Comment: If both properties are `DateTime?` why don't you just do `EffectiveDate = m.StartDate` ? Also where is this exception thrown? Please show the code where you actually use `filteredMembers`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a repro and it works as expected. I don't think that StartDate is the issue here. I think you misinterpret where the NullReferenceException is coming from.

My guess is that your members list contains a null reference.

Comment: Initially I thought so. But if I used EffectiveDate = m.StartDate ?? DateTime.Now then it works fine. If the members list had a null reference, it would have faield here also. It fails only when the StartDate is null. If any of the strings were null, then it works fine.

Comment: You are not using Linq to SQL, right? This is pure Linq to Objects(?). Would you please post an executable repro?

Comment: It is not Linq To Sql. It is Linq To Object. But the objects are retrieved from an intranet webservice running on java/oracle.

Comment: Ok, can you post an executable repo? Just new up some object and put it in a hardcoded array.